# How do I build an ubuntu cloud image file with a custom kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling, arm64

I want to replace the kernel and related kernel-specific files in a cloud image file (like those from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/) for ubuntu 20.04.  I can build my own kernel following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel, but can not find the tooling to assemble a new cloud image with the new kernel-specific files replacing those on an existing cloud image file.

I would also like to do this in a cross compilation environment, eg build on an amd64 targeted for an arm64. The https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel is silent on this matter, and the linked-to page at the bottom is 10 years old, and smells deprecated (and does not discuss arm64).

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I'm also looking to do this, and struggling to find good documentation to build a KVM flavour kernel (ubuntu-cloud) for use in a cloud environment to add support for cilium networking with kubernetes.

I followed the guide mentioned here and got the kernel sources from

[https://code.launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-kvm/+git/jammy](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-kvm/+git/jammy)

and guessed the command

**`LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean ; LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-kvm`**

adapted from the suggestion

`# if you need linux-tools or lowlatency kernel, run instead: LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary`

However the resultant packages were not installed successfully due to package conflict with the installed version. you would need to edit the version in debian.kvm/changelog as opposed to debian.master/changelog as this is for generics it seems.